# How to filter a specific column in excel using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.10

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("C:\ktl.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
```

This is the code I have so far, as I don't know what to do next. So basically I want to open
"C:\ktl.xlsx" and make python filter column five for me, when I give the word "SPT098".
So it should filter column five for that word and all the rows related to that and then save the results in another excel file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you are looking for. I am assuming some random data in kt1.xlsx. This script will use pandas (not openpyxl, hope that is ok) to read the data into a dataframe df, ask the user for the value to be filtered and create and store data filtered by that column into a new excel file, output.xlsx.

**The sample data in ktl.xlsx**

```
Col_Date            Col_Num Col_2   Name    FilterByCol
25-06-2022 4.00     700     532     aa      SPT098
25-06-2022 5.00     1100    433     aa      SPT099
25-06-2022 6.00     800     754     aa      SPT064
25-06-2022 7.00     1200    288     aa      SPT153
25-06-2022 8.00     700     643     bb      SPT098
25-06-2022 9.00     1400    668     bb      SPT099
25-06-2022 10.00    1600    286     bb      SPT064
03-06-2022 11.00    397     46      cc      SPT153
03-06-2022 12.00    100     7       cc      SPT098
03-06-2022 13.00    400     25      cc      SPT099
03-06-2022 14.00    500     41      cc      SPT064
03-06-2022 15.00    400     0       cc      SPT153
03-06-2022 16.00    300     23      dd      SPT098
03-06-2022 17.00    500     50      dd      SPT099
03-06-2022 18.00    300     0       dd      SPT064
03-06-2022 19.00    400     15      dd      SPT153
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C:\ktl.xlsx", "Sheet1") #Read data from Sheet1 into df
filter_val = input("Please provide the filter_by value: ") #Ask user input - SPT098
if filter_val not in df.iloc[:,4].unique():
    print("Invalid entry. Exiting...")  # Exit in case of incorrect data
else:
    df=df[df['FilterByCol'] == filter_val]
    df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
    print("Processing complete. Filtered data written to output.xlsx")
```

**Output in excel for SPT098**

[image]

Comment: Sir there is a problem as when I run it after asking me the name it just says incorrect data and it exits. How to fix it. Also I want to do it for AYV013 instead of SPT098. Kindly help in this sir. I am also getting a keyerror = FIlterByCol ??? Pls help me in this.